# why doesn't the text get centered?it becomes on the right edge

Tags: html, css

why doesn't the text get centered?
it becomes on the right edge
what should i change?

```css
   .text4 {
      width: 762px;
      height: 714px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 40px;
      color: #273d46;
      font-family: "Times New Roman";
      text-align: center;
  }
```

```html
<div class="text4">
      Donec aredsed odio dui. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum
      at eros. Morbi leo risus, porta ac consectetur ac, vestibulum at eros. Donec
      ullamcorper nulla non metus auctor fringilla.
      Aenean eu leo quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum. Aenean eu leo 
      quam. Pellentesque ornare sem lacinia quam venenatis vestibulum.
</div>
```

Comment: it is aligned center

Comment: but i have text on the left side of the screen, not centered

Comment: in this code text is aligned center. show more code please.

Comment: I noticed you have a width set for the text which means that the parent may be positioning it differently. Please post some more code to replicate the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in this code text should be aligned center.
I think your text4 position is not center.
try like this

```
.text4 {
      width: 762px;
      height: 714px;
      font-size: 24px;
      line-height: 40px;
      color: #273d46;
      font-family: "Times New Roman";
      text-align: center;
      margin:auto;
}
```